# What is the meaning of normalization in machine learning language? Does it correspond to one sample?

Tags: python, machine-learning, normalization

I am dealing with a classification problem I want to classify data into 2 classes. I generate 1000 samples at different temperatures ranging from 1 to 5. I load data using following function load_data. Where "data" is 2 dimensional array (1000,16), Rows correspond to number of samples at "1.0.npy" and similarly for other points and 16 is number of features. So I picked max and min values from each sample by applying a for loop. But I'm afraid that my normalization is not correct because I'm not sure what is the strategy of normalization in machine learning. Should I pick np.amax(each sample) or should I pick np.amax("1.0.npy") mean from all 1000 samples that contained in 1.0.npy files. My goal is to normalize data between 0 and 1.

```
`def load_data():
    path ="./directory"
    files =sorted(os.listdir(path))  #{1.0.npy, 2.0.npy,.....5.0.npy}
    dictData ={}

    for df in sorted(files):
        print(df)
        data = np.load(os.path.join(path,df))
        a=data
        lis =[]
        for i in range(len(data)):
            old_range = np.amax(a[i]) - np.amin(a[i])

            new_range = 1 - 0
            f = ((a[i] - np.amin(a[i])) / old_range)*new_range + 0

            lis.append(f)`
```

After normalization I get following result such that first value of every sample is 0 and last value is one. 
    `[0, ...., 1] #first sample
    [0,.....,1]   #second sample`

Comment: There is no clear single definition for "normalization". And as for ML the usual rule applies: try different things, keep what works best.

Comment: But there must be some preferred situation as far as my above code is concerned.